# What does "::" syntax mean?

Tags: php, fuelphp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

In PHP what does `::` mean? e.g

```
Pagination::set_config($config);
```

Is it analogous to `=>` ?

Comment: The name of :: is Paamayim Nekudotayim.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks for that - various searches in the SO search box failed to answer my question.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey - i didn't downvote you! And i did search... just didn't "hit" the right term.

Comment: okay. apologies then. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called Scope Resolution Operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 4):

In PHP it is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). It is used to access methods and attributes of uninitiated classes. Methods which are made explicit for this notation are called **static methods**.

Furthermore you can use this notation to traverse through extended classes relatively (from the position where you are). Example:

```
class betterClass extends basicClass {
    protected function doTheMagic() {
       $result = parent::doTheMagic();
       echo "this will output the result: " . $result;
       return $result;
    }
}
```

In this example the doTheMagic method overwrites the existing method of its parent, but with `parent::doTheMagic();` the original method can be called, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

This "::"-syntax is called **Scope Resolution Operator**.

It's used to refer to function and variables in base classes or classes that haven't got any instances yet.

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am the original function A::example().<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am the redefined function B::example().<br />\n";
        A::example();
    }
}

// there is no object of class A.
// this will print
//   I am the original function A::example().<br />
A::example();

// create an object of class B.
$b = new B;

// this will print 
//   I am the redefined function B::example().<br />
//   I am the original function A::example().<br />
$b->example();
?>
```

Just read the comments in the example. For more information, go to [the php.net article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Answer (score 0):

`::` is a *scope resolution operator* (originally named so in C++) means you're associating the`set_config($config)` method with the class `Pagination`. It's a static method and static methods can not be accessed through the objects of it's class, since they are associated with their class rather than the objects of that class.

```
Pagination::set_config($config);
```

The notation -> is used to access instance members. The notation `=>` is used with associative arrays in PHP to access the members of those arrays.